# How can i create jasper report without getting values from DB?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm creating a application for a medical laboratory. So When user Enter the resulting values to text boxes and click the submit button. Then create the report using that resulting values before values go to the database.I'm using jasper reports. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a bean datasource for your report, rather than a datasource to a database. So, instead of feeding data direct from a database, you feed it a collection of custom beans (basic POJOs).

A good example can be found here: http://javabeansinjasper.blogspot.co.uk/

The steps you need to follow are:

1) Create single POJO for report

2) Create report template (using iReport) which references the properties of your POJO. So, say for a class Person, you may have a property called firstName. In the report template this would be referenced with $F{firstName}

3) Compile your report and load your collection into it via a datasource:

```
Person p = ...;
List<Person> persons = ...;
persons.add(p);
Map parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("/path/to/report/template.jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(persons));
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"PersonsReport.pdf");
```

Comment: @Harshana Samarayaka Why has this answer been unaccepted?